# PHP Mkdir if folder doesn't exist, if it does continue but add an incrementing value to the name each time

Tags: php, mkdir

I'm checking to see if a folder exists by using the file_exists function.

If it doesn't, I'm creating a set of folders.

If it does exist, I want it to carry on creating the folders but the top folder should increment an id #1 , #2 , #3 etc each time.

```
if (file_exists('temp/$email')) {
    mkdir("temp/$email/");  
    mkdir("temp/$email/css");  
    mkdir("temp/$email/js");  
    mkdir("temp/$email/images"); 

} else {

    $version = 0;
    $version++;

    mkdir("temp/$email$version/");  
    mkdir("temp/$email$version/css");  
    mkdir("temp/$email$version/js");  
    mkdir("temp/$email$version/images"); 
}
```

Something along the lines of this but obviously that won't work. How can I go about doing this?

Also - is there a cleaner / simpler way of doing multiple mkdirs instead of writing them out in a long list like how I've done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more efficient solution for you, also handles creating the subdirectories without a big list of `mkdir`.

You can define subdirectories like `a/deeper/sub/directory` and it will create the full path.

Some default values to make the code work:

```
define('BASE_DIR', 'temp/');

$email = 'hello';

$subdirs = array(
    'css',
    'js',
    'images'
);
```

Improved loop:

```
$version = '';

if (file_exists(BASE_DIR . $email)) {
    $version = 0;
    while (file_exists(BASE_DIR . $email . (++$version)));
}
```

Create your subdirectories:

```
foreach ($subdirs as $dir) {
    mkdir(BASE_DIR . $email . $version . '/' . $dir, 0777, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_exists('temp/'.$email)) {
    $version = 1;
    while (file_exists('temp/'.$email.$version)) {
        $version ++;
    }
} else {
    $version = "";
}
mkdir("temp/".$email.$version."/");  
// etc
```

You should put a sanity check there too, to make sure you don't get an infinite loop.

Comment: lovely. I'll give this a try in a bit then come back and give you the answer :) thanks!

Comment: Make sure to grab the latest-edited version - the old one would have had one of theose infinite loops I mentioned ;-)